# If $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$ then is $X/{\sim}$ homeomorphic to $Y/{\sim'}$?/

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a homeomorphism between topological spaces. Suppose we have an equivalence relation $\sim$ defined on $X$. Define an equivalence $\sim'$ on $Y$ by $y_1\sim'y_2$ iff $x_1\sim x_2$ where $y_i=f(x_i)$

> Is $X/{\sim}$ homeomorphic to $Y/{\sim'}$?

I have a well defined continuous map $F:X/{\sim}\to Y/{\sim'}$ given by $[x]\mapsto[f(x)]$. This can easily be seen to be bijective. I am having trouble proving that this is open. I know there is some diagram chasing involved but I am confused.

We have the following commutative diagram -
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    X @>f>> Y\\
    @Vq_XVV\circlearrowright @VVq_YV\\
    X/{\sim}@>>F> Y/{\sim'}
\end{CD}

If $U$ is open in $X/\sim$ then $q_X^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ and $f(q_X^{-1}(U))$ is open in $Y$. To prove that $F(U)$ is open in $Y/\sim'$ we need to show that $q_Y^{-1}(F(U))$ is open in $Y$. This will be true if $f(q_X^{-1}(U))=q_Y^{-1}(F(U))$. But I am having trouble proving this is equality. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: "I have a well defined continuous map...". Then the map $[y]\mapsto[f^{-1}(y)]$ will be well defined and continuous as well. It will serve as inverse of the map $[x]\mapsto[f(x)]$.

Comment: if you proved that $F$ is continuous then the very same (mutatis mutandis) proof should gives you that $F^{-1}$ is continous

Comment: So you know how to do commutative diagrams in MathJax, but you don't know the conspicuous difference between the following things: $$ 
\begin{align} & X/{\sim} \\ & X/\sim \end{align} $$ There is a reason why the latter is coded as it is. Can you figure out what that reason is, and why the software was designed to work that way? (I edited the quesiton to correct this.) $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you proved that $F$ is continuous then the very same (mutatis mutandis) proof should give you that $F^{-1}$ is continuous, just swap the role of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: You are right. I missed a very simple thing :( Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

On one side, we have $$
  f(q_X^{-1}(U)) = \{ f(x) | q_X(x) \in U \}.
$$

On the other, we have
\begin{align*}
  q_Y^{-1}(F(U)) &= q_Y^{-1}(\{ [f(x)] | q_X(x) \in U \})
  = \big\{ y \big| [y] \in\{ [f(x)] | q_X(x) \in U \}\big\}.
\end{align*}

But if $y$ is such that there is a $x$ such that $q_Y(y) = [f(x)]$, then $y \sim' f(x)$.  But then, $f^{-1}(y) \sim x$.  Thus $f^{-1}(y) \in q_X^{-1}(U)$.  Thus $y = f(x')$ for some $x'$ in $q_X^{-1}(U)$, therefore you can conclude that
$$
q_Y^{-1}(F(U)) = \big\{ f(x') \big| q_X(x') \in U \text{ and } [f(x')] \in \{[f(x)]|q_X(x)\in U\}\big\} = \{f(x')|q_X(x') \in U \}
$$

The first equality simply replaces $y$ by "$x'$ such that $q_X(x') \in U$" and the second equality is obvious.  Thus the two sets of the equality to be proven are indeed equals.

Comment: Why are you using $q_X (x)$ explicitly rather than the equivalence class notation? Is a specific reason for that?